# Vincenty's Formula Symbols

Tags: geodesy

I have been researching about Vincenty's formula for my new programme but through many books I didn't find any explanation about the upper case A, upper case B and u square . Does someone knows what are there meaning?

I have read the https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf and https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html but none of them explain what is upper A, upper B and u square, and where are they from.
Thanks

Comment: As far as I see T. Vincenty definites on p. 88, 89, $a,b$ as the major and minor semiaxes of the ellipsoid, $\alpha$ as the azimuth of the geodesic at the equator, and $A,B,u^2$ are just abbreviations of expressions using those variables.

Comment: I am doing a mini research and my teacher told to explain their meaning. So I just write that A and B is a and b abbreviation? And u^2 is alfa abbreviation? Because I don't why it needs to put in such equation. Thank you

Comment: Vincenty doesn't say it and I don't know.

Comment: Vincenty says "The recomended direct and inverse solution were developed from Rainsford's inverse formula [3]. The direct solution was obtained by reversing the inverse, using the approach of Rapp [4]."  Have you investigated those references?  They probably explain where the formulas come from.